# Замена символов в массиве char - C

Tags: c, строки

Задача: исходная строка (`char`) содержит числа десятичной системы счисления. Найти их, создать новую строку, в которой заменить числа десятичной системы счисления на их же номинал в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления. Нечисла же надо оставить на своих местах.

Пример: `444444asdf` должен преобразовываться в `6C81Casdf`.

Использовать стандартные функции и библиотеки нельзя.

Мой код может переводить только числа, если строка содержит символы букв, то не работает. Прошу посодействовать.

Моя реализация:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inputChar(char *str)
{
    printf("input array char <100: ");
    scanf("%s", str);
}
void revers(char *A)
{
    int j;
    for (j = 0; A[j] != '\0'; j++);
    j--;
    for (int i = 0; i <j; i++, j--)
    {
        char temp = A[i];
        A[i] = A[j];
        A[j] = temp;
    }
}
int charToDecInt(char *A)
{
    int summ = 0;
    for (int i = 0; A[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {        
        if ('0' <= A[i] && A[i] <= '9')
        {
            summ *= 10;
            summ += A[i] - '0';
        }
        else
        {
            summ += A[i]-'A'+10;
        }

    }
    return summ;
}
void decIntTohexString(int a, char *A)
{
    int j = 0;
    while (a != 0)
    {
        int r = a % 16;
        if (r >= 1 && r <= 9)
        {
            r += '0';
        }
        else 
        {
            r += 'A'- 10;
        }
        A[j++] = r+A[j];
        a /= 16;
    }
    A[j] = '\0';
    revers(A);
}
void display()
{
    const int N = 100;
    char A[N] = "";
    char B[N] = "";
    inputChar(A);
    int a = charToDecInt(A);
    decIntTohexString(a, B);
    printf("hexChar = %s\n", B);
}
int main()
{
    display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: С какой проблемой вы столкнулись? В чём заключается вопрос?

Comment: мой код делает так: исходная строка - (например) 444444, строка на выходе 6C81C. Т.е. он отлично переводит числа из dec в hex. Но если строка содержит символы букв, то начинаются проблемы. нужно чтобы было так: (например) 444444asdf - > 6C81Casdf

Comment: То что он отлично переводит, это хорошо. Ну а затруднения в чём? Насколько я понимаю, вы же не просто так задали вопрос, а для решения какой-то проблемы.

Comment: Проблема именно в этом и заключается, собственно говоря. Мой код из dec в hex переводит только если исходная строка состоит только из символов цифр. Если она содержит символы букв, то код не работает. Исходная строка не должна изменяться, в ней должны только меняться числа в десятичной системе счисления на на эти же числа в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления.

Comment: Не знаю, у меня всё работает: https://ideone.com/6GSmhI. То есть лишние буквы дублирует сама консоль, но не программа.

Comment: код работает только если в исходной строке символы цифр. А нужно чтобы он работал и в том случае если входная строка и буквы содержит. Понятно что он из 444444 сделает 6C81C. А если исходная строка 444444asdf то на выходе будет 6C8DE, а должно быть 6C81Casdf.т.е. в строке на выходе буквы не должны меняться, а заменяются только числа

Comment: Еще один пример, чтобы совсем стало все понятно: на входе у вас строка "163 of the year", а на выходе должно получиться: "0xA3 of the year". Т.е. исходная строка сохраняется в ней происходит замена только чисел с dec на hex.

Comment: А, теперь дошло. Сейчас напишу ответ.

Comment: Вы отредактировали, и написали, что "нечисловой элемент строки должен перенестись в конец строки". Это неверно. Нечисловые элементы строки должны остаться на своем месте. У вас просто происходит замена чисел. Входная строка: "163 of the year" на выходе строка:"0xA3 of the year". А если на входе так: "the year 163", то на выходе должно быть: "the year 0xA3". Происходит только замена числа

Comment: Исправил обратно.

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно в цикле много ошибок. Но все равно ничего не работает

Comment: Исправьте строку `inputChar(itA);` на `inputChar(A);`. Я случайно функции чтения неинициализированный указатель скормил.

Comment: Я исправил. Дело не в этом. Просто Ваша программа теперь удаляет из строки все нечисловые символы.  Ваша реализация работает так: на входе строка: "163 of the year", а на выходе строка " 0xA3", т.е все буквы удаляются, а число выводится. А нужно чтобы исходная строка переносилась в выходную строку полностью, только с заменой числа. Чтобы было вот так: "163 of the year" - на входе, а вот так на выходе "0xA3 of the year"

Comment: Представьте, что у нас есть строка на входе, которая содержит буквы, пробелы и числа представленные в десятичной системе счисления. Так вот на выходе должна получится точно эта же строка, с точно этими же числами, только представленными в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления. Вместо чисел представленных в dec мы их заменяем на числа в hex. Вот еще один пример (для простоты на русском). На входе строка: Например: "на складе 444 лежит 163 товара", на выходе должно получится: "на складе 0x1BC лежит 0xA3 товара".

Comment: ...и я не заметил проверок на переполнения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Текущая реализация функции `charToDecInt()` содержит логическую ошибку:

   ```
   int charToDecInt(char *A)
   {
       int summ = 0;
       for (int i = 0; A[i] != '\0'; i++)
       {        
           if ('0' <= A[i] && A[i] <= '9')
           {
               summ *= 10;
               summ += A[i] - '0';
           }
           else                      // <--  (1)
           {
               summ += A[i]-'A'+10;
           }

       }
       return summ;
   }
   ```

   Альтернативная ветвь условия (строка `(1)`) ловит не только буквы в диапазоне `[a-hA-h]`, но и вообще любые нецифровые символы. Поэтому цикл, встретив первую нешестнадцатеричную цифру, испортит всё формируемое число.

   Решением проблемы является остановка цикла при встрече не только конца строки (`\0`), но и нечислового символа. Для этого надо переписать шапку цикла следующим образом:

   ```
   for (
       int i = 0;
       A[i] != '\0' && ((A[i] >= '0' && A[i] <= '9') || (A[i] >= 'A' && A[i] <= 'H'));
       i++
   )
   ```
2. Для вывода окончания строки в нетронутом виде необходимо отслеживать его положение. Самый оптимальный вариант отслеживания — прямо во время разбора числа. В этом случае конец разбора будет совпадать с началом нетронутой строки.

   Иными словами, мы должны возвращать из `charToDecInt()` не только разобранное число, но и позицию окончания разбора.

   Так как это Си, не поддерживающий возврата кортежей, то позицию придётся возвращать через один из параметров функции:

   ```
   int charToDecInt(const char *A, const char **outPos)
   {
       int summ = 0;
       int i = 0;          // <--
       for (
           A[i] != '\0' && ((A[i] >= '0' && A[i] <= '9') || (A[i] >= 'A' && A[i] <= 'H'));
           i++
       )
       {        
           if ('0' <= A[i] && A[i] <= '9')
           {
               summ *= 10;
               summ += A[i] - '0';
           }
           else
               summ += A[i]-'A'+10;

       }
       *outPos = A + i;   // <--
       return summ;
   }
   ```

   Соответственно, придётся переделать и вывод разобранных чисел.

   1. Для удобства вывода сделаем так, чтобы `decIntTohexString()` возвращала количество записанных символов.

      ```
      int decIntTohexString(int a, char *A)
      {
          int j = 0;
          while (a != 0)
          {
              int r = a % 16;
              if (r >= 1 && r <= 9)
              {
                  r += '0';
              }
              else 
              {
                  r += 'A'- 10;
              }
              A[j++] = r+A[j];
              a /= 16;
          }
          A[j] = '\0';
          revers(A);
          return A + j;   // <-- да, мы возвращаем указатель на нуль-символ (всё равно затрём)
      }
      ```
   2. Начнём с `display()`. Так как чисел внутри строки может быть несколько, и все они разделены символами, отличными от шестнадцатеричных чисел, поиск и разбор придётся производить в цикле. В изначальной реализации программа брала только самое первое число.

      ```
      int charToDecInt(char *A, char** outPos)
      {
          // ...
      }

      int decIntTohexString(int a, char *A)
      {
          // ...
      }

      void display()
      {
          #define N 100
          char A[N] = "";
          char B[N] = "";

          inputChar(A);

          const char *itA = A;
          char *itB = B;
          while(*itA && itB - B < N)
          {
              // Ищем начало очередного числа
              while(*itA != '\0' && !((*itA >= '0' && *itA <= '9') || (*itA >= 'A' && *itA <= 'H'))
                  ++itA;

              int a = charToDecInt(itA, &itA);

              // Выводим разобранное число
              itB = decIntTohexString(a, itB);
              printf("%s", itB );
      }
      ```

Comment: Если интересно, то я решил данную задачу. Без использования стандартных функций и библиотек. И без использования указателей.

Answer (score 0):

Кому интересно я решил свою задачу (без использования стандартных функций и библиотек и без использования указателей):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int strLen(char *S)
{
    int n;
    for (n = 0; S[n] != '\0'; n++);
    return n;
}
void revers(char *A)
{
    int j;
    for (j = 0; A[j] != '\0'; j++);
    j--;
    for (int i = 0; i <j; i++, j--)
    {
        char temp = A[i];
        A[i] = A[j];
        A[j] = temp;
    }
}
void digitDecToHexString(int digit, char *T)
{
    int j = 0;
    while (digit != 0)
    {
        int r = digit % 16;
        if (r >= 1 && r <= 9)
        {
            r += '0';
        }
        else
        {
            r += 'A' - 10;
        }
        T[j++] = r;
        digit /= 16;
    }
    T[j] = '\0';
    revers(T);
}
void intDecToCharHex(char *A, char *B)
{
    int n = strLen(A);
    char Hex[1000] = "";
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int v = 0;
    int p = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if ('0' <= A[i] && A[i] <= '9')
        {
            v = v * 10 + (A[i] - '0');
            k = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (k == 1)
            {
                    digitDecToHexString(v, Hex);
                    B[j++] = '0';
                    B[j++] = 'x';
                    for (p = 0; p < strLen(Hex); p++)
                    {
                       B[j++] = Hex[p];
                    }
            }
            B[j++] = A[i];
            k = 0;
            v = 0;
        }
    }
    if (k == 1)
    {
        digitDecToHexString(v, Hex);
        B[j++] = '0';
        B[j++] = 'x';
        for (p = 0; p < strLen(Hex); p++)
        {
             B[j++] = Hex[p];
        }
    }
}
void inputCharArray(char *S)
{
    printf("Введите строку на латинском алфавите размерностью мене 1000 символов: \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", S);
}
void display()
{
    char A[1000] = { '\0' };
    inputCharArray(A);
    char B[1000] = "";
    intDecToCharHex(A, B);
    printf("Входная строка: \n%s\n", A);
    printf("Строка после обработки: \n%s\n", B);

}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    display();
    return 0;
}
```